# How do I utilize a different OpenGL profile?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I would like to replicate tutorials (sprite rendering), that use OpenGL version >= 3.3.

Geometry shaders for example were introduced in 3.2, and I get this error:

```
error: ‘GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER’ was not declared in this scope
```

I updated my mesa driver to the latest; I don't really understand though, how I can choose a newer version of OpenGL when compiling/linking in c++:

➜ glxinfo | grep -i "version"

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Version: 17.1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.1.4
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.1.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 17.1.4
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

I cannot really interpret this, but it says there is some kind of core profile using version 4.5. How do I utilize this profile?

I initialize the GL context in my code like this:

```
if(!glfwInit()) e_glfw_init();
m_window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_TITLE.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
if(m_window == nullptr) e_window_context();
glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window);
glewExperimental = true;
if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) e_glew_init();
```

Comment: How do you initialize your context?

Comment: What OpenGL headers/loading libraries are you using?

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm including these headers:

`GL/glew.h`
`GLFW/glfw3.h`
`glm/glm.hpp`
`GL/glu.h`
`glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp`

Comment: @NicolBolas These are my precompiled libraries passed to the compiler:
`-lGL -lGLU -lglut -lGLEW -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -ldl -lXinerama -lXcursor -lSOIL`

Comment: Please show the code where you initialize the context. Without seeing what you do, it is impossible to give you any hints

Comment: @Spektre it's in the last line though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [glfw documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html#quick_create_window), you can specify the OpenGL version and profile by using the [`glfwWindowHint`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hints) function:

```
if(!glfwInit()) e_glfw_init();

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 5);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

m_window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_TITLE.c_str(),
                            nullptr, nullptr);
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to change the window's OpenGL version, I want to get the features of newer OpenGL when compiling my code. (basically include a newer header and link a newer pre-compiled library / shared object)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "newer" library or header file. All methods and extensions are loaded from this one library (that's what `glewInit` does). `GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER` should be defined in the current `glew.h` header file.

Comment: Thanks I'll try and find the definition!

Comment: `glewInit` should be loading all function pointers for core extensions. Geometry shaders shouldn't be a problem unless he gets a < 3.3 context.

Answer (score -1):

I had solved this issue on Linux by including these three headers when while playing with GLFW and shaders:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
```

Comment: Please don't write your answer in all caps. It looks like you are shouting.